# Getting the node with the greatest number of neighbors of a specified condition in a graph

Tags: python, graph

I'm working with a networkx graph `graph` in which each node is converted to an object with specified attributes such `node_x.colour` where `x in range(0, len(graph))`. All node objects are stored in `self.nodes = [...]`. Each node also has an associated neighbors list `adjacent_nodes = [...]` which contains the indices of the graph nodes it is connected to and is accessed via `node_x.adjacent_nodes`.

I have a separate list `voting_nodes = [...]` which stores all the nodes in `graph` that have an attribute of 'opinion' equal to 1 i.e. if `node_x.opinion = 1`, append it to `voting_nodes`

I want to get the node `i` in the `graph` such that `node_i in voting_nodes` and has the most neighbors in `voting_nodes` out of all other nodes in `voting_nodes`.

My attempt was:

```
max_vote_count = 0

# Voting node with the most voting neighbors. Will be type object.
best_voting_node = 0

for node in voting_nodes:
    vote_count = 0
    if node.adjacent_nodes:
        for neigh_node in node.adjacent_nodes:

            # self.nodes[neigh_node] gets the corresponding node object of index neigh_node
            if self.nodes[neigh_node] in voting_nodes:
               vote_count += 1

            if vote_count > max_vote_count:
               max_vote_count = vote_count
               best_voting_node = node
```

However, the code returns `0` as the `max_vote_count` and `best_voting_node` everytime, even if nearly all nodes in `graph` are connected. What is the error and is there a better approach?